# error in parsing style in layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, parsing

I am trying to set style for image button in android layout but it gives me this error in Eclipse:

```
app_download_detail.xml: Failed to parse file N:\My Projects\app\res\drawable\title_home.xml

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:167)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
    at .....
```

-----> this problem is solved by update my Adt to new version... thnx of all..

Comment: give the code of title_home.xml

Comment: please post the code in the question itself. Not as a comment. edit your question and paste it in.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set the 'drawable' property  for an item of the layout you are inflating at line 167 in your `StateListDrawable.java` file according to the error.

go through the xml file and set the missing drawable property and you should be fine.

Comment: how i can do that?thnx:)